# raw_input issue where the input needs to be checked against a list before accepting the input

Tags: python-2.7

This will be very simple to someone out there but for me at a basic new to it level is giving me a headache.

I need a user to input an educational grade A, B, C, D, E, or F.

I want either lower or upper case to be acceptable but for any other input value for it to loop until they do.

So far I have written this:

```
grades = (raw_input("Please enter your educational grade either as A, B, C, D, E or F: "))

# checking for truthiness
while grades != ("A", "a", "B", "b", "C", "c", "D", "d", "E", "e", "F", "f"):
    print ("The grade you entered does not conform.")
    grades = (raw_input("Please enter your educational grade either as A, B, C, D, E or F: "))

# display valid input
print ("Your input is valid, you entered:  "), grades
```

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: side note, you can simplify the need for capitalization check but converting the user input to all uppercase (or similiarly lowercase), with something like `grades = raw_input("Please enter your educational grade either as A, B, C, D, E or F: ").upper()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using either `str.upper()` or `str.lower()` will work for checking user input, but be consistent that it matches the case used in the list in the `while` loop. This is a little repetitive/redundant, but I think satisfies your requirement:

```
grades = raw_input("Please enter your educational grade either as A, B, C, D, E or F: ").upper()

while grades not in(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]): 
    print ("The grade you entered does not conform.")
    grades = raw_input("Please enter your educational grade either as A, B, C, D, E or F: ").upper()

print ("Your input is valid, you entered: "), grades
```

Or, a `while True:` loop version that accomplishes the same thing, but moves prompting for user input inside the loop, reducing code repetition.

```
while True:
    grades = raw_input("Please enter your educational grade either as A, B, C, D, E or F: ").upper()
    if grades not in(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]):
        print ("The grade you entered does not conform.")
    else:
        print ("Your input is valid, you entered: "), grades
        break
```

Comment: Hi downshift works fine for what i need but what do you mean by a little repetitive / redundant? What would you do differently?

Comment: Hi ChrisC,  sorry for my vague comment, I meant that in my answer I am assigning grades twice, which I think looks kind of confusing. Whereas I would prefer using a `while True:` loop at the beginning and check if the input is valid inside the loop then break out of the loop. It's just personal preference, I think -- both ways function the same, but it's just a little more clear to me what the code is doing when there's less repetition.

Comment: I am just bowled over by the fact that someone has helped me :)

Comment: You're very welcome, aww, I'm honored that I've helped you. That's what this community should be all about. Glad to help you my friend :)

Comment: By the way, if I did indeed help and it answered your question, consider upvoting and/or check marking the green check next to it. :) (shameless plug) thank you, and cheers :)

Comment: green tick ticked,  upvoting ? sorry but very new and not sure what this is

Comment: Thank you! Oh my apologies, the up/down arrows(or they look like triangles) (above and below) the green tick mark, you can click the up/down to give an answer a vote, it's not really useful when there's only one answer here, but when a question gets many answers, voting is the way good answers get recognized. see more here https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote. My apologies if that was confusing.